# Scatterplot with different colored outliers and geom text number labels

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, colors, geom-text

I have a data frame with multiple columns. Here is an example.

```
my_df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c(50, 22, 15, 33, 49))
colnames(my_df) <- c("ID", "values")
my_df
```

I am trying to make a scatterplot where there are subsets of this data frame as outliers that are have separate colors to the non-outliers. On top of this, I am also trying to label these outliers with their associated number.
Here is an example attempt:

`ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x = seq(1, length(values)), y = my_df$values))+
  geom_point(data = subset(my_df, values > 48), aes(color = "blue"))+
  geom_point(data = subset(my_df, values < 24, aes(color = "red"))+
  geom_text(data = subset(my_df, values > 48), aes(label = values))`

The geom_text line of code provides this error.

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): colour, x, y

Secondly, I have tried using ifelse to separate values by different colors as a different attempt - however, I do not know a way to label the different color sections with numbers, or even with a legend with names for each color section. Here is an example, but even with added geom_text, or attempts at adding a legend, what I intend on making will not work out. Here is the code that works as a baseline:

```
ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x = seq(1, length(values)), y = my_df$values))+
  geom_point(color = ifelse(my_df$values > 25, "red", "blue"))
```

If anyone can help, I'll be so thankful, as I've been struggling with this for over a week now.

EDIT: The answers provided below have answered my question. This is the code for my resulting plot, including a legend title and names for each variable as a reference for those looking this up afterwards.

```
ggplot(my_df, aes(ID, values, color = factor(cut(values, c(0,24,48,Inf))))) +
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_text_repel(data = . %>% filter(values> 48), aes(label = values), show.legend = F)+
  geom_text_repel(data = . %>% filter(values< 24), aes(label = values), show.legend = F)+
  labs(title = "Beautiful Scatterplot", x = "ID", y = "Values", color = "Legend Title") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Below 24", "Between 24 and 48", "Above 48"), values = c("blue", "red", "purple"))
```

[Example Answer Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMpmS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
my_df %>% 
  mutate(col=case_when(values > 48 ~ 4,
                       values < 24 ~ 2,
                       T ~ 1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, values, color = factor(col))) +
   geom_point(size=3) + 
   geom_text_repel(data = . %>% filter(values> 48), aes(label = values)) + 
   scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Or using only `ggplot`

```
  ggplot(my_df, aes(ID, values, color = factor(cut(values, c(0,24,48,Inf))))) +
   geom_point(size=3) + 
   geom_text_repel(data = . %>% filter(values> 48), aes(label = values), show.legend = F)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: If you are happy with it, please consider to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data=my_df,aes(x=ID,y=values,label=ifelse(values>48,values,"")))+
  geom_point(size=4,color = ifelse(my_df$values > 48, "red", "blue"))+
  geom_text(vjust = 1.3,nudge_x = 0.15,aes(colour="red"),fontface = "bold",show.legend=F)
```

[image]

Comment: not a good idea to adopt wrong syntax like `y=my_df$values`  within `aes()` in an answer.

Comment: This is very useful - Thank you !